# Fql query returns with no results

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I am working in C# with multi Queries.

```
        var query1 = string.Format("SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {0}", "me()");
        var query2 = string.Format("SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = {0}", "me()");
```

The first query works fine and returns ok. The second query returns OK with no data. Why?

Comment: could u post the full code on how you do the request. fb.Query(...) Incase you are getting no data on the second one may be coz there is no data. if your query is wrong you will get different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your app needs the "user_photos" permissions in order to get that information (data from the "album" table).

Check this out: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with me and how did I miss that - Thank you